# Upcoming changes to Android External Storage Permissions

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, android-external-storage

Using Visual Studio 2019

Future changes to Android OS appear to place restrictions on using external storage. My App currently stores a database and 300+ images on the SD card. I have successfully moved the sqlite database to internal storage and am now wondering where I can place my image library. Can the user install the images in a public Pictures folder? I currently use the following to manage my images:

```
public static class ImageAssetManager
{
    public static Dictionary<string, Drawable> cache = new Dictionary<string, Drawable>();

    public static Drawable Get(string url)
    {
        string imageurl;
        imageurl = Vars.DataLoc + "Images/" + url;
        if (!cache.ContainsKey(imageurl))
        {
            Drawable drawable;
            drawable = Drawable.CreateFromPath(imageurl);
            cache.Add(imageurl, drawable);
        }
        return cache[imageurl];
    }
}
```

**Vars.DataLoc** is the root path to the external storage, and **url** is the name of the requested image.

Where can I have the user store the images and how do I modify the above routine to work with the new storage location? I could theoretically store them in the Assets folder (like I do with the database) and have the the system write them out to LocalApplicationData, but the number and names of the files are not static.

I have to support devices as old as KitKat, if possible. Since this App is usually used where there is no internet connection, all files must be local.

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: There is nothing in your code that tells us which path(s) you use. Further tell Android version of used devices.

Comment: `Future changes to Android OS appear to place restrictions on using external storage.` Where have you been all that time? That was already for Android 10 and 11. Google is now busy with 12 and you can too ;-)

Comment: The App, as submitted over a year ago, worked fine using external storage. It hasn't needed any updates until recently. Google is strongly recommending that Apps don't use external storage. The question is: Where CAN I have the user place the images so that they are accessible to all current and upcoming releases of the OS? It needs to work for Android 4.4 and later.

Comment: You can write your images to the public DCIM or Pictures folder or to your own subdirectories of them.